# Prove that $P(X \le a) + P\{Y \le \frac{1}{a}\} = 1$

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study, cumulative-distribution-function, f-distribution

Prove that if $X$ has the F-distribution with $(m, n)$ d.f. and $Y$ has the
F-distribution with $(n, m)$ d.f., then for every $a > 0$,
$$
P(X \le a) + P\left\{Y \le \frac{1}{a}\right\} = 1
$$
I tried solving  $P(X \le a)$ by integration but it was too difficult for me.
How do I approach questions like these in general?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Please add the self-study tag, read it’s wiki, and post what progress you’ve made so far with your homework assignment.

Comment: Use the properties of the F-distribution. In particular, if $X \sim F_{m,n}$, what is the distribution of the reciprocal $Y=\frac{1}{X}$?

Answer (score 5):

I will give you some clues toward a proof and, I hope, some idea why
this equality is of interest.

**Definition and simulation.** First, the distribution $\mathsf{F}(m,n)$ is defined as the distribution
of the ratio of two independent chi-squared random variables, each divided
by its degrees of freedom (so that numerator and denominator both have mean $1).$
It follows that $Y = 1/X \sim \mathsf{F}(n,m).$

```
set.seed(2020)
Num = rchisq(10^6, 10)/10
Den = rchisq(10^6, 15)/15
F.rat = Num/Den
summary(F.rat)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
 0.02225  0.65241  0.97911  1.15450  1.45158 21.39064
```

The graph below shows the simulated values of `F.rat` along with the
density function of $\mathsf{F}(10, 15).$ The positions of quantiles .025 and
0.975 are shown by vertical dotted lines.

```
hdr="Simulated Values of F(10,15) with Density"
hist(F.rat, prob=T, br=50, col="skyblue2", ylim=c(0,.9), main=hdr)
 curve(df(x,10,15), add=T, col="brown", lwd=2, n=1001)
 abline(v=qf(c(.025,.975), 10, 15), col="red")
```

[image]

**Motivation: Printed tables of F-distributions.** Typically, printed tables
of F-distribution give just a few 'percentage points' for each pair of degrees
of freedom: in my table. 'percentage points' $.25, .1, .05, .025, .001,$ which
cut those percentages of probability from the *upper* tail of each distribution.
These amount to quantiles $.75, .9, .95, .975, .999.$ These vaues are chosen
because of their frequent use to make confidence intervals and for tests involving
F-distributions.

However, values that cut particular values from the *lower* tails of F-distributions
are often of use, even though they are not provided in most printed F-tables.
(Nowadays, this is hardly causes difficulty because statistical calculators and
computer software provide almost any quantiles of practical interest.)

Suppose that for $X \sim \mathsf{F}(10, 15),$ I want to know the value $q$ such that
$P(X \le k) = 0.025,$ which is not in my F-table. From R, I can find that $k = 0.2840.$

```
k = qf(.025, 10, 15);  k
[1] 0.2839559
pf(k, 10, 15)
[1] 0.025
```

Now let's look at some additional values for relevant F distributions. The following
information is in my table: percentage point 0.975 is 3.52. In R, this is equivalent to
the following (where some extra decimal places are available):

```
h = qf(.975, 15, 10);  h
[1] 3.521673
pf(h, 15, 10)
[1] 0.975
```

Your equation $P(X \le a) + P\left(\frac{1}{X} \le \frac 1a\right) = 1$ can be
illustrated in R as follows:

```
pf(h, 15, 10) + pf(1/h, 10, 15);  1/h
[1] 1
[1] 0.2839559    # 1/h
```

Notice that the information from the second term, $P\left(\frac{1}{X} \le 1/h\right)$ is
not available in a printed table because it involves the 'lower half' of
$Y = 1/X \sim \mathsf{F}(10,15).$

```
pf(1/h, 1, 15)
[1] 0.398074
```

It follows that we can find the value that cuts probability $0.025$ from the *lower*
tail of $\mathsf{F}(10,15)$ from a printed table. It can be found as the reciprocal of the value that cuts
$0.025$ from the *upper* tail of $\mathsf{F}(15, 10).$

```
 1 / qf(.975, 15,10)
 [1] 0.2839559       # can be found from table
 qf(.025, 10, 15)
 [1] 0.2839559       # not explicitly printed in table
```

Comment: This gave me the intuition for the question but I still don't know how to proof this mathematically.

Comment: The right tail of F(m,n) tells you much about the left tail of F(n,m) because of the reciprocal relationship from the definition of an F distribution.

Answer (score 4):

I will share three general techniques for working with density functions that are remarkably simple and useful: *normalization,* *scaling,* and *identifying symmetries.*  (A fourth general technique, *recentering,* often is useful but isn't applicable in this situation.)

By following these principles, along with a healthy application of the "principle of mathematical laziness," **you can just *look at* a formula for the F-Ratio density and deduce the symmetry relationship expressed in the question.**

#### Normalization

**The Normalization Principle**

Any function $f$ that is never negative, can be integrated, and has a finite integral $I[f]$ corresponds to a density: all we need do is divide all the values of $f$ by its integral and the result satisfies all the properties of a density.

When you are examining any mathematical expression for $f,$ then, it often is convenient just to ignore any *constant* multiplicative factors that may appear.  ("Constant" means they don't depend on the argument of $f$ -- but often they may depend on other quantities, usually known as "parameters.")  Those factors will be determined by the integral of all the other factors.  Let's call this the **"Normalization Principle."**

In this case, one expression for the F-Ratio density (from the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution#Definition)) is

$$f(x;d_1,d_2) = \color{blue}{\frac{1}{B\left(\frac{d_1}{2},\frac{d_2}{2}\right)} \left(\frac{d_1}{d_2}\right)^{\frac{d_1}{2}}}\, x^{\frac{d_1}{2}-1}\left(1 + \frac{d_1}{d_2}x\right)^{-\frac{d_1+d_2}{2}}.\tag{1}$$

I have colored some terms that do not depend on the argument $x:$ *we are free to ignore these, because they are determined by the Normalization Principle.*

**You have choices**

*There is always more than one way to partition a density's expression into a constant factor and the other factors.*  Indeed, you may even introduce new factors in the expression if that helps you simplify or understand it -- so long as they don't depend on the function's argument.  I will illustrate this in the next section, where I expand the blue factors to include more terms that appear.

#### Scaling

Distributions are best analyzed by examining the *entire* expression that you would integrate.  This expression is sometimes called the *probability element:* it is the product of the density $f_X(x)$ (representing the height on its graph) and the *differential element* $\mathrm{d}x$ (representing small distances along the base of the graph of $f_X$).  The product has units of probability -- and it's the probability, not the density, that behaves most simply under analysis.

Consider, then, a probability element $f_X(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ and suppose you were to change the units of measurement in which $x$ is expressed.  For instance, if $x$ represents a length in centimeters and you prefer to work in inches, you would divide $x$ by $2.54$ centimeters per inch.  This obviously doesn't change anything about any probabilities: it merely reflects how you choose to write down numbers.

Mathematically, when we divide $x$ by a positive number $\lambda$ to produce $y=x/\lambda,$ the new probability element $f_Y$ is therefore written

$$f_Y(y)\,\mathrm{d}y = f_X(x/\lambda)\,\mathrm{d}( x / \lambda ) = f_X( x)\,\mathrm{d}(\lambda x/ \lambda ) = f_X(x/ \lambda )\,\left(\mathrm{d}x\right)/ \lambda  = \frac{1}{\lambda} \left(f_X(x/ \lambda )\,\mathrm{d}x\right).$$

If now, as is conventional, we omit writing the differential elements $\mathrm{d}y$ and $\mathrm{d}x,$ the preceding equation reads

$$f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{\lambda} f_X(x/ \lambda ).\tag{2}$$

The appearance of the factor of $\lambda$ is a mystery until you appreciate it is the last visible trace of the now-vanished differential element.  Let's call this the **"density scaling law."**  (Understanding how $f_X$ changes when $x$ is transformed also permits us to drop the subscripts from $f$ from now on.)

*Exploit the density scaling law by working backwards.* Whenever you look at the mathematical expression of a density, look for constant terms that multiply the argument: these are candidates for the *scale factor* $1/\lambda.$

Let's re-examine the F-Ratio density $(1)$ from this perspective.  It contains two terms with "$x$" in it.  Focus on the simplest one:

$$f(x;d_1,d_2) = \frac{1}{B\left(\frac{d_1}{2},\frac{d_2}{2}\right)} \left(\frac{d_1}{d_2}\right)^{\frac{d_1}{2}}\, x^{\frac{d_1}{2}-1}\left(1 + \color{red}{\frac{d_1}{d_2}x}\right)^{-\frac{d_1+d_2}{2}}.$$

There it is in red, all by itself, multiplied by a constant $d_1/d_2 = 1/\lambda.$  What you want to do is replace $x/\lambda$ by $y$ or, equivalently, just plug $\lambda y = d_2/d_1 y$ into the formula everywhere in place of $x.$  In so doing you will be neglecting that ghostly $\lambda$ factor that appeared in $(2),$ *but the Normalization Principle tells us this doesn't matter.*

This is a perfectly routine substitution, requiring only basic algebra to simplify:

$$\begin{aligned}
f(y;d_1,d_2) &\propto \frac{1}{B\left(\frac{d_1}{2},\frac{d_2}{2}\right)} \left(\frac{d_1}{d_2}\right)^{\frac{d_1}{2}}\, (d_2/d_1\, y)^{\frac{d_1}{2}-1}\left(1 + \color{red}{\frac{d_1}{d_2}(d_2/d_1\, y)}\right)^{-\frac{d_1+d_2}{2}}\\
&= \color{blue}{\frac{1}{B\left(\frac{d_1}{2},\frac{d_2}{2}\right)} \left(\frac{d_1}{d_2}\right)^{\frac{d_1}{2}}\, \left(\frac{d_2}{d_1}\right)^{\frac{d_1}{2}-1}}\,  y^{\frac{d_1}{2}-1}\left(1 + \color{red}{y}\right)^{-\frac{d_1+d_2}{2}}
\end{aligned}
.$$

Although there is an obvious nice cancellation of the fractions involving $d_1/d_2$ and $d_2/d_1,$ I didn't bother to go further with the simplification because the Normalization Principle tells us we don't have to do any more work: these new factors merely contribute to the multiplicative "fluff" that we may freely ignore.  That's why I am showing all of it in blue.

Notice the appearance at the outset of the "$\propto$" ("is proportional to") relation: it acknowledges that I neglected to divide the right hand side by $\lambda = d_2/d_1.$

These last two steps are examples of what I call the [**Principle of Mathematical Laziness:**](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=principle+mathematical+laziness) *don't do calculations until you have to, because often you will discover you don't have to do them at all.*

Invoking the Normalization Principle once more, let's look at what's left of $f:$

$$f(y;d_1,d_2)\ \propto\ y^{\frac{d_1}{2}-1}\left(1 + y\right)^{-\frac{d_1+d_2}{2}}.\tag{3}$$

Let's call this the "nucleus" of $f:$ any factors multiplying its argument $y$ have been stripped away and any constant factors multiplying its value have been ignored.  Typically, *you can just **look** at the formula of a density and see its nucleus.*  It usually takes no work at all.

#### Symmetry

The appearance of $-1$ in the power of $y$ in the nucleus $(3),$ along with the fact that $f$ is supported on the positive numbers $(0,\infty),$ hints at a [multiplicative symmetry](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/185709/919).  (For more on the $-1$ terms in the powers, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/263842/919.)

Symmetry is a powerful, general concept that I can only hint at here by showing how it applies to the F-Ratio distribution.

The beautiful thing about the differential element $\mathrm{d}y/y$ is how it transforms when we take powers of $y:$

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}(y^p)}{y^p} =\frac{py^{p-1}\mathrm{d}y}{y^p} = p\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y}\ \propto\ \pm\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y}.$$

This is, after invoking the Normalization Principle, $\mathrm{d}y/y$ *does not change* when we take a positive power of $y$ and otherwise, for negative powers, it is merely negated.  The negation reflects the fact that transforming $y$ to a negative power of $y$ reverses order: when $x \gt y \gt 0$ and $p\lt 0,$ $0 \lt x^p \lt y^p.$  We need to keep track of any such reversals because they subtly change the interpretation of $f:$ more about this at the end.

Take the appearance of "$-1$" in the power of $y$ in the nucleus $(3)$ as an invitation to rewrite the density as a differential element in terms of $\mathrm{d}y/y.$  This is the final simplification:

> $$f(y;d_1,d_2)\,\mathrm{d}y\ \propto\ y^{\frac{d_1}{2}}\left(1 + y\right)^{-\frac{d_1+d_2}{2}}\,\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y}.\tag{4}$$

Upon applying the transformation $y = u^{-1}$ in the question, *without any work at all* we immediately see

$$f(u;d_1,d_2)\,\mathrm{d}u\ \propto\ -(u^{-1})^{\frac{d_1}{2}}\left(1 + u^{-1}\right)^{-\frac{d_1+d_2}{2}}\,\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u} = \frac{(u^{-1})^{\frac{d_1}{2}}}{\left(1 + u^{-1}\right)^{\frac{d_1+d_2}{2}}}\,\left(-\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u}\right).$$

Simplifying the fraction (in the usual manner) by multiplying numerator and denominator by a suitable power of $u$ (namely, the $(d_1+d_2)/2$ power) yields

$$f(u;d_1,d_2)\,\mathrm{d}u\ \propto\ \frac{u^{\frac{d_2}{2}}}{\left(1 + u\right)^{\frac{d_1+d_2}{2}}}\,\left(-\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u}\right) =u^{\frac{d_2}{2}}\left(1 + u\right)^{-\frac{d_1+d_2}{2}}\,\left(-\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u}\right).\tag{5}$$

**Comparing $(5)$ to $(4)$ shows that upon transforming $y$ to $1/y,$ the kernel with parameters $(d_1,d_2)$ becomes the kernel with parameters $(d_2,d_1)$ *with a negative sign*.**

#### Conclusion

The appearance of the negative sign means that at some point we transformed the variables in an order-reversing way.  Originally, to compute the probability of an interval $(-\infty, a]$ we would have integrated the probability element over the interval $(0, a].$  Because of the transformations we made, we must transform its endpoint $a$ appropriately to some new value $a^\prime$ and, *due to the order reversal,* we must now integrate over the interval $[a^\prime, \infty).$

Because the integral will be the same whether or not we include $a^\prime$ in that interval, the conclusion in the question follows immediately: when $X$ has an F-Ratio distribution with parameters $d_1,d_2$ we may compute $\Pr(X\le a)$ either by integrating $f_X$ from $0$ to $a$ or by integrating $f_U = f_{1/X},$ which has an F-Ratio distribution with parameters $d_2,d_1,$ from $a^\prime = 1/a$ to $\infty,$ which of course is just $1 - \Pr(U \le 1/a).$

---

**If you would like to practice these techniques further,** virtually every distribution (over 40 of them) in the [Wikipedia list of continuous distributions supported on semi-infinite intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions#Supported_on_semi-infinite_intervals,_usually_%5B0,%E2%88%9E)) can be analyzed in the same way.