# Generating random samples obeying the exponential distribution with a given min and max

Tags: exponential-distribution, software, truncated-distributions

Random samples obeying the [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) can be generated by the [inverse sampling technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Generating_exponential_variates) by using the quantile function of the exponential distribution:

$$
x = F^{-1}(u) = - \frac{1}{\lambda} \ln(u)
$$

where $u$ is a sample drawn from the [uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_uniform_distribution) on the unit interval $(0, 1)$.

In [OpenFOAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenFOAM) software, a distribution model called `exponential` ([here](https://github.com/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-dev/blob/master/src/lagrangian/distributionModels/exponential/exponential.C#L75)) can be used to generate exponential-distribution random samples, and its users can, supposedly, **choose a minimum and maximum value** for the exponential-distribution samples **prior to** the random-number generation.

The [governing expression implemented into this software](https://github.com/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-dev/blob/master/src/lagrangian/distributionModels/exponential/exponential.C#L75) is as follows:

$$
x = -\frac{1}{\lambda} \ln \left[ \exp(-\lambda t_{min}) + u \{\exp(-\lambda t_{max}) - \exp(-\lambda t_{min})\} \right]
$$

where $t_{min}$ and $t_{max}$ are user-defined minimum and maximum values, respectively.

Two (rather broad) questions arise:

1. Have you ever come across the above expression (or similar one) in the literature for generating exponential-distribution random samples with a given min-max? Or do you think this expression looks like (or is) a heuristic solution?
2. If heuristic, would you suggest a way to carry out verification tests on this expression to test whether the expression produces samples obeying the exponential distribution within [min,max]? (Plotting normalised histogram (i.e. counts in a bin divided by the number of observations times the bin width) and comparing it with the analytical exponential distribution seem to be problematic due to the min/max limits).

Comment: This expression inverts the CDF.  It is exact.  This is not a discrete distribution, however, so what do you mean by "discrete" random samples??

Comment: Removed the 'discrete' term. Is the second equation also the inverted CDF? The min and max variables thereat confuse me.

Comment: The first equation inverts the exponential CDF.  The second inverts the truncated exponential CDF.

Comment: please post this little sentence as an answer, so that I can hit the accept button.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You describe truncation to an interval.  I will elaborate.

Suppose $X$ is any random variable (such as an exponential variable) and let $F_X$ be its distribution function,

$$F_X(x) = \Pr(X\le x).$$

For an interval $[a,b],$ the *truncation* limits $X$ to that interval.  That lops off some probability from $X,$ namely the chance that $X$ either is less than $a$ or greater than $b.$  The chance that is left is

$$\Pr(X\in[a,b]) = \Pr(X\le b) - \Pr(X\le a) + \Pr(X=a) = F_X(b) - F_X(a) + \Pr(X=a).$$

Thus, to make the total probability come out to $1,$ the distribution function for the truncated $X$ must be zero when $x\lt a,$ $1$ when $x\ge b,$ and otherwise is

$$F_X(x;a,b) = \frac{\Pr(X\in[a,x])}{\Pr(X\in[a,b])}= \frac{F_X(x) - F_X(a) + \Pr(X=a)}{F_X(b) - F_X(a) + \Pr(X=a)}.$$

When you can compute the inverse of the distribution function--which almost always means $X$ is a continuous variable--it's straightforward to generate samples: draw a uniform random probability $U$ (from the interval $[0,1],$ of course) and find a number $x$ for which $F_X(x) = U.$  This value is written

$$x = F^{-1}_X(U).$$

$F_X^{-1}$ is called the "percentage point function" or "inverse distribution function."

For example, when $X$ has an Exponential distribution with rate $\lambda \gt 0,$

$$U = F_X(x) = 1 - \exp(-\lambda x),$$

which we can solve to obtain

$$F_X^{-1}(U) = -\frac{1}{\lambda}\log(U).$$

This is called "inverting the distribution" or "applying the percentage point function."

It turns out--and this is the point of this post--that *when you can invert $F_X,$ you can also invert the truncated distribution.*  Given $U,$ this amounts to solving

> $$U = F_X(x;a,b) = \frac{F_X(x)-F_X(a)}{F_X(b) - F_X(a)},$$

because (since we are now assuming $X$ is continuous) the terms $\Pr(X=a)=0$ drop out.  The solution is

> $$x = F_X^{-1}(U;a,b) = F_X^{-1}\left(F_X(a)+\left[F_X(b) - F_X(a)\right]U\right).$$

That is, the *only* change is that after drawing $U,$ you must rescale and shift it to make its value lie between $F_X(a)$ and $F_X(b),$ and *then* you invert it.

This yields the second formula in the question.

An equivalent procedure is to draw a uniform value $V$ from the interval $[F_X(a),F_X(b)]$ and compute $F_X^{-1}(V).$  This works because the scaled and shifted version of $U$ has a uniform distribution in this interval.  I use this method in the code below.

[image: Figure]

The figure illustrates the results of this algorithm with $\lambda=1/2$ and truncation to the interval $[2,7].$  I think it alone is a pretty good verification of the procedure.

The `R` code is general-purpose: replace `ff` (which implements $F_X$) and `f.inv` (which implements $F^{-1}_X$) with the corresponding functions for *any* continuous random variable.

```
#
# Provide a CDF and its percentage point function.
#
lambda <- 1/2
ff <- function(x) pexp(x, lambda)
f.inv <- function(q) qexp(q, lambda)
#
# Specify the interval of truncation.
#
a <- 2
b <- 7
#
# Simulate data and truncated data.
#
n <- 1e6
x <- f.inv(runif(n))
x.trunc <- f.inv(runif(n, ff(a), ff(b)))
#
# Draw histograms.
#
dx <- (b - a) / 25
bins <- seq(a - ceiling((a - min(x))/dx)*dx, max(x)+dx, by=dx)

h <- hist(x.trunc, breaks=bins, plot=FALSE)
hist(x, breaks=bins, freq=FALSE, ylim=c(0, max(h$density)), col="#e0e0e0",
     xlab="Value", 
     main="Histogram of X and its truncated version")
plot(h, add=TRUE, freq=FALSE, col="#2020ff40")

abline(v = c(a,b), lty=3, lwd=2)
mtext(c(expression(a), expression(b)), at = c(a, b), side=1, line=0.25)
```

Comment: this answer is literally amazing.

Answer (score 4):

[whuber](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/919/whuber) has given you a general answer showing the overall technique.  I will give you a shorter answer that focuses only on your specific case.  Note that there is an answer to a similar question (using the same method but for the truncated normal distribution) [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/113230/373441#373441).

---

You have already pointed out the technique of inverse-transform sampling, which involves generating a random quantile from the uniform distribution $U \sim \text{U}(0,1)$.  When sampling within a truncated interval, you need merely adjust this procedure so that you generate a random quantile *over the range of allowable quantiles* for the truncated interval, giving a restricted random quantile $R \sim \text{U}(q_\min,q_\max)$.

Now, if $X \sim \text{Exp}(\lambda)$ then the relevant quantile values are obtained by substituting the boundaries of the interval into the CDF, giving:$^\dagger$

$$q_\min = F(t_\min) = \exp(-\lambda t_\min)
\quad \quad \quad 
q_\max = F(t_\max) = \exp(-\lambda t_\max).$$

Since $R \sim \text{U}(q_\min,q_\max)$ we can obtain this value from the random variable $U \sim \text{U}(0,1)$ using the transformation:

$$\begin{align}
r 
&= q_\min + u (q_\max - q_\min) \\[6pt]
&= \exp(-\lambda t_\min) + u (\exp(-\lambda t_\max) - \exp(-\lambda t_\min)). \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

Thus, inverse-transformation sampling gives the formula used by the software:

$$\begin{align}
x 
&= -\frac{1}{\lambda} \ln (r) \\[6pt]
&= -\frac{1}{\lambda} \ln \bigg( \exp(-\lambda t_\min) + u (\exp(-\lambda t_\max) - \exp(-\lambda t_\min)) \bigg). \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

---

$^\dagger$ Here I am making use of the fact that the distribution is continuous to gloss over a slight complication; see [whuber](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/919/whuber)'s answer for more detail on the general case.

Comment: a very beautiful and useful answer as well.

Comment: just a minor point: the last equation might missing the negative sign?

Comment: The point isn't quite that minor, because the wrong expression for $F$ was used here.  The correct one is $F(t)=1-\exp(-\lambda t).$